# Cannot Drag Most Objects to Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I've got a project with a few working views.

After the upgrade to Xcode 6.1, I cannot drag a UITableViewController and most other objects to any of my views.  I can drag simple objects like UIButton or UILabel to my views.

Anyone with a tip on this?

Answer (score 1):

you can not add uitableviewcontroller in uiviews not even in previous versions of xcode. you should drag and drop uitableview not uitableviewcontroller.

Comment: Correct, of course.  Don't know why an option to drag the view controller is so prominent in scoreboard.